# VBA loop to copy data from dynamic number of sheets to first sheet, copying too many times

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am still pretty new at VBA but I am trying to loop through and copy a dynamic amount of sheets data (these change monthly and vary in length) and not include the first two sheets and last sheet.  The data starts on the 6th row and I would like to copy all contents to the first sheets last row named Combined_Athlete.  The code I have below actually works but is looping through the data 5 times and copying duplicates of the content into the first tab.  Can anyone help and tell me where I am going wrong?  I set the second variable to copy the data from the 6th row to the last since that is where it starts but I am not sure if that is the cause of the 5 times of extra data that it's copying.  Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub CopyAndCombineSheets()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    For i = 3 To Worksheets.Count - 1

        For Each ws In Worksheets
        Worksheets(i).Select

        LastRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

                For j = 6 To LastRow
                    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(j).Copy Sheets("Combined_Athlete").Range("A" & Sheets("Combined_Athlete").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
                Next j

        Next ws

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping twice through all the sheets. Try something like this:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Combined_Athlete" then
        LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 6 To LastRow
            ws.Rows(j).Copy Sheets("Combined_Athlete").Range("A" & Sheets("Combined_Athlete").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        Next j
    End if
Next ws
```

Comment: Thanks!  I actually tried that and I get an error because it is not finding the ActiveSheet now, do I need to activate it somewhere in the loop maybe?

Comment: @Michelley16 - See my edited code (such a stupid mistake...sorry about that)